# Does changing a item field in a Collection while iterating invalidates the collection?

Tags: c#, iterator, enumerators

If do:

```
foreach(var a in col) {
     a.X = 1;
}
```

Will my iterator over the collection become invalid?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. You can access the members of the items in the collection. Your code is valid.

What you can't do is modifying the collection itself (by removing or adding items to it) while iterating.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't cause a problem. Only if you try to modify the contents of `col` by doing `col.Remove` or `col.Add` would I imagine there would be a problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone:) 

I was in doubt because this sentence in doc:

"If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, *modifying*, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its behavior is undefined."

Comment: I guess in this context 'modifying' refers to replacing an element of the collection.